`Slot must increase` error when requesting EVM pending state
When requesting a state through the EVM using the "pending" parameter with the following command:
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "eth_getStorageAt", "params": ["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0x0", "pending"], "id": 1}' 127.0.0.1:9999

The node panics with the following error:
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "error":
    {
      "code":-32603,"message":"Create pending runtime api error: Failed to call runtime API, Execution failed: Runtime panicked: Slot must increase"
    }
  "id":1
}


Steps to Reproduce

Go to https://github.com/freeverseio/laos/tree/fix/deploy-contract-using-hardhat
Run a local network using Zombienet
Wait until parachain starts producing blocks
Run the following command: curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "eth_getStorageAt", "params": ["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0x0", "pending"], "id": 1}' 127.0.0.1:9999
See error


I realized that the pending API uses the DigestItem to inform the runtime about the next slot. Since the slot is calculated using the current timestamp, the resulting slot is the same as the one received from the pallet. Therefore, it makes sense that the Slot must increase error is raised.
I fixed this by sending an advanced timestamp in the inherent data providers.
